# Android C2DM - What to send in http post?

Tags: android, http, android-c2dm

I have set up the client and gotten the "token/registration_ID", as per Lars Vogel' guide and the android developer blog...

But i want to test this before going onwards with the server part, so i was thinking of testing it with [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/details) which when choosing POST method looks like this:
[image: Image of Advanced Rest client]

Now taking into consideration the different aspects i need to send:
registration_id,collapse_key,data.,delay_while_idle,Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=[AUTH_TOKEN].

How do i write these so it sends it correctly in headers/body and what syntax? i see peoples servercode sperate things with &, is that how it is done?

edit:

tried like this, gets 0 back as response...
[image]

Comment: You can use CURL command for testing proposes

Comment: And yes CURL does look good aswell.

Answer (score 1):

You can send Binary data, which is byte array or large data which exceeds 255 character's limit.

Please visit a C2DM Example [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html). It is very simple and step by step process.

Comment: I think you should re-read my question, i have explicitly said i made my client from lars vogel's guide ( the one you refer too ).
No where in it though does it say anything about the layout of the http request. he just whips his merry wand and makes it..

Answer (score 0):

Has to do this over 2 requests, one to get the auth key, second to send the message... GCM is way easier